# Why were the SpaceX ninjas (pad crew) using a stepladder to move something?

Tags: spacex, dragon-v2, launch-sequence

On the second launch attempt of the Dragon Crew Demo 2 (human spaceflight), sometime lower than 1:50:00 to launch, the ninjas spend about 5 minutes on a stepladder, dealing with a tube and box, which they fasten above the gantry. It didn't seem to be on the first launch, though it could have easily occurred during video cutaways. Based on how the Ninjas crowded around it, it seems off-nominal but also not a problem.

Here's the step-by-step I saw:

- 1:50:00 (minus a bit) Christina Koch is on screen. Ladder is brought out.
- Ninja 5 is on the ladder.
- Ninja 19 holds a plastic bag, puts the box/filter in it.
- Ninja 5 is on the ladder.
- Once Ninja 5 comes off, 5 and 9 fasten it above the opening. It appears to be a bit of a struggle.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Keep in mind this is an ORANGE tube, not the grey/black tube that is pushed through the hatch, which is presumably related to air conditioning. I didn't see the orange tube on the first video or at any other point. And